# EditText not getting selected, but popping keyboard up

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

My soft keyboard pops up on an activity with an edit text, but I still have to press the edit text to be able to type into it, otherwise pressing keys on the keyboard do nothing

I am using `requestFocus()` as well as `android:focusable="true"` as well as `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

thoughts?

I do not have another edit text in this activity or within the fragment that also loads in this activity (hope thats a clue for someone, because I am out of ideas, for now)

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:hint="@string/write_something"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/ten_dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

Manifest Entry

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

Comment: Can we see the xml and the manifest for the activity?

Comment: @zgc7009 okay, edited. I even tried with <requestFocus/> in the XML wrapped by the edittext tag

Comment: windowSoftInputMode stateVisible tells your activity that you want the keyboard to be visible when the activity starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was having the EditText `requestFocus()` after 200 milliseconds, using the postDelayed method of the view

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works for me):

```
myEditText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, 0, null);
```

And you don't have to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` for your activity.

Comment: why would that work, just curious? the keyboard already shows

Comment: @CQM because it says to show keyboard for a particular view.